# String memory allocation in java

Tags: java, string, memory

In an Servlet class, I am having the checks

if("Mail".equals( request.getParameter(mode)) || "Chat".equals( request.getParameter(mode)))
{}

My question is about the memory allocated for the strings "Mail" and "Chat". Will it create new string objects for every request to this servlet. What about GC?.

Comment: If you ever traced the amount of code executed just schedulaing a servlet you would not worry about such micro optimisations!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it won't create a new object each time. String constants are *interned* - they're created once and put in a special pool.

Not only will it not create a new string each time you run the code, but if you use the constants "Mail" or "Chat" elsewhere in your code, they'll use the same string objects too.

From the Java Language Specification [section 3.10.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5):

> Each string literal is a reference (§4.3) to an instance (§4.3.1, §12.5) of class String (§4.3.3). String objects have a constant value. String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28)-are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

Comment: Jon, In some other thread I asked you `""` does it also get stored in pool , and how much memory it consumes. I would like to know

Comment: @org.life.java: Yes, it does get stored in the pool. It won't take up much memory - enough for an empty char array and the `String` object itself, basically.

Comment: So it only makes sense to store Strings as `static final` if you use them a lot in your class and don't want to risk typos, right?

Comment: @cringe: In terms of memory usage, yes. But keeping consistency is pretty important...